# How does it work if you halve something twice? Multiplicative or Additive?

Tags: spells

Basically I'm a Wizard and I have Slow, which "halves the targets speed". My Cleric friend has Spirit Guardians, which also halves targets' speed. Im curious whether the targets speed would then be 0 or 1/4 of their speed (7.5?)? Is there anything about this in the handbook?

Comment: What game and edition are you asking about? Please include a tag to indicate this. There are thousands of RPGs and we can't provide an answer without knowing which one the question is about.

Comment: The classes, spells, and their effects line up well with D&D 5E, but it's not much detail to go on. Can you confirm this?

Comment: *Slow* has been a wizard spell in just about every edition of D&D. *Spirit guardians* has been a cleric spell in other editions, too, I believe, though I don’t know offhand if it slows enemies down in any others. But it’s all-too-plausible that the 5e version descends from a version in an earlier edition. As such, we really can’t even guess the edition here, and cannot answer without it.

Comment: It might even be possible that this might be another game entirely, like Shadowrun. IIRC there's a Slow spell and summonable Guardian Spirits.

Comment: Cward, just to make this absolutely clear (since the UI unfortunately isn't), the *only* thing wrong with your question is that you haven't specified which game and edition you are playing, and we're not supposed to guess if it's not 100% clear. If you [edit your question](/posts/192518/edit) and add the missing information, it will be reopened and (almost certainly) answered.

Comment: @nick012000 Unlikely. No edition of Shadowrun I've heard of features wizards, clerics, or base movement being consistent across characters, let alone being 30 of anything. This is reasonably some flavor of D&D.

Comment: @StopBeingEvil "No edition of Shadowrun I've heard of features wizards, clerics," Technically, every edition of Shadowrun features wizards, they just tend to be called "hermetic mages" instead. Similarly, clerics are just Christian or Muslim religious leaders, and it's entirely possible for then to be magically awakened. ;)

Comment: @nick012000 "They call them hermetic mages instead" is my point.